# What is the RegionsVersion property used with the Google Play Developer API?

Tags: google-api, google-play-console

I am trying to use the Google Play Developer API to patch a subscription using the REST endpoint.

https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/rest/v3/monetization.subscriptions/patch

The required query parameters are `updatedMask` and `regionsVersion`. When I click on the `RegionsVersion` for documentation it just says:

> A string representing version of the available regions being used for
> the specified resource.

https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/rest/v3/RegionsVersion

Based on that description I'm not sure what kind of value it's expecting other than an object with a version property that is a string. When I omit the `regionsVersion` parameter is returns the following error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": 400,
        "message": "Regions version should be set to the default value 2022/01.",
        "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
    }
}
```

Does anyone have any idea or an example of how this required parameter is intended to be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue and I found that since it's s JSON object you'll have to set its property like that with query params:

`?updateMask=listings&regionsVersion.version=2022/01`

This worked fine for me!

Comment: Fyi the latest version is 2022/02 - very important for Croatia's currency change.